# Thailand Visa On Arrival for Indians when not traveling directly from India

Tags: visas, india, thailand, visas-on-arrival

I know that Thailand provides Visa On Arrival facility for Indians. But, I will be traveling from Jakarta, Indonesia to Bangkok, Thailand, and then staying in Thailand for 1 day. My question is am I still valid for Visa On Arrival even though I am not directly traveling from India?

Comment: It’s your citizenship that counts, not where you’re arriving from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will get visa on arrival based on the citizenship, not the country where I am coming from. I have successfully obtained the VOA when coming from Cambodia.

PS: [The visa on arrival fees is waived till April 30, 2019](https://www.thai.lt/blog/761-thailand-visa-on-arrival-fees-waiver-extended-in-2019).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell how much time will it take in the Airport to get Visa on Arrival. I want to inquire about that because my flight will land late in the night. And also, will it help if I fill the Visa On Arrival form online beforehand and just give that form when I arrive in Bangkok?

Comment: It will take around 15 minutes. You need to show your return ticket, proof of funds of 20,000 Thai Bhat (they accepted an ATM slip) and accomodation. Also need a photo of specific size.

Yes, you can ask and fill arrival form beforehand, if possible.